# Printing (char) A through (n) recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I seem to be close, but I can't seem to figure out a way to print out the original letter. With my current code, if I input "e", I want to print out a b c d e. However, my code only prints out a b c d, and not e. I know this is because 'c' gets subtracted because it can print out e, but I can't figure out how to print it out from e to a while printing it out backwards.

```
public static void letters(char c)
{
    if (c > 'a')
    {
        letters(--c);
    } else {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(c + " ");
}
```

Comment: else {System.out.print(c+" "); return;}

Comment: Did you try removing the `return` statement and avoid decrementing `c`?

Comment: You could change `letters(--c);` to `letters(c-1);`  Then your first character would still be `e` when you came to print it.

Comment: yeah its c-1 instead of --c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You decrement `c` and then later eventually print it which means you will *never* print the original value. Change your code to

```
public static void letters(char c) {
    if (c > 'a') {
        letters((char)(c - 1)); // do not decrement c
    } // no else block since we dont need it
    System.out.print(c + " ");
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for that. However, I don't understand the different between letters((char)(c-1)) and letters(--c), since aren't you decreasing c by 1? (--c and c-1)

Comment: @Hmm no, the first one changes the, the second one does not, both result in the same value returned name "one less than c was originally" but one leaves c as it is and one changes it.